# Connection lost: The server closed the connection - Best way to handle?

Tags: node.js

What is the best way to handle `Connection lost: The server closed the connection.`

My code is running on GCP and I'm using Cloud Run for my API and Cloud SQL for my MySQL DB. I'm using Sentry logging and I'm seeing a handful of these everyday (not the same queries every time).

My questions are:

- Why does this happen?
- What is the best way to handle it? Would it just be a try/catch block where a new connection is created in the catch block and the function re-executed? If so, it doesn't seem like a very efficient solution.